How do I use logical operators with dynamic arrays?
I have the following table where we have the same ID and date. However, I want to create an array that changes the ID based on the ID and the date.
The formula I have tried is:
=IF(AND(DROP(TAKE(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),1)=12345,
 DROP(TAKE(B:B,COUNTA(A:A)),1)<DATE(2024,1,1)),"54321",
 DROP(TAKE(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),1))

but record 3 is not giving correct answer


For the sample data provided there would be no need to include AND: =LET(L,MATCH(2,1/A:A),IF(B2:INDEX(B:B,L)<45292,54321,A2:INDEX(A:A,L))) or =LET(x,LAMBDA(y,FILTER(y,IFERROR(--B:B,0))),IF(x(B:B)<45292,54321,x(A:A)))

@P.b Sir, your formula will not work, if you change the last id as 12346 it will keep as 54321 as in it should be 12346 since the ID is not equal to 12345 and hence therefore the AND() is required here to catch all the conditions!

With given samples it wouldn't matter. Else you're correct.

You could try using the following formula:


=IF((A2:A4=12345)*(B2:B4<DATE(2024,1,1)),54321,A2:A4)


Or, can use the following as well, this assumes the ID column as the based for the last row, you don;t need a LAMBDA() helper function here, and instead of using AND() function use the * operator :
=LET(
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _ID, DROP(TAKE(A:A,_LastRow),1),
     _Date, DROP(TAKE(B:B,_LastRow),1),
     IF((_ID=12345)*(_Date<DATE(2024,1,1)),54321,_ID))


 NOTE: Use of * because in Boolean logical operation the rules states that, multiplication corresponds to AND() logical function, while addition + corresponds to OR() logical function.

Addendum: If you want to use AND() function specifically, you would need LAMBDA() helper functions like MAP():
=LET(
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _ID, DROP(TAKE(A:A,_LastRow),1),
     _Date, DROP(TAKE(B:B,_LastRow),1),
     MAP(_ID,_Date,LAMBDA(α,δ,
     IF(AND(α=12345,δ<DATE(2024,1,1)),54321,α))))



Dropping another take,
=LAMBDA(data, from_id, to_id, before_date_,
    LET(
        data, DROP(TAKE(data, COUNTA(TAKE(data, , 1))), 1),
        id, INDEX(data, 0, 1),
        date_, TAKE(data, , -1),
        IF((id = from_id) * (date_ < before_date_), to_id, id)
    )
)($A:$B, 12345, "54321", DATE(2024, 1, 1))


